# first_name is added to the tuple

Tags: django

Im using [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/). I added more fields in form (firstn_name and last_name) in form:
***myapp/forms.py***

```
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label="first_name", strip=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "name", }))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='last_name', strip=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'last_name',}))

 def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name'],
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        return user
```

after which I specified a link to this form in the settings. When registering, these two fields appeared, but:

Now, when registering, my first_name is in the tuple.

[image]

I output in the template:

```
{{user.first_name}}
```

Last name is displayed normally.
What can be done so that the first name is not in a tuple, but just a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma at the end of your `user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name'],`

Remove the comma and it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be an easy fix, there is a comma at the end of `user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name'],`, and Django is treating this as a tuple.

Your `forms.py` should look like this:

```
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label="first_name", strip=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "name", }))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='last_name', strip=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'last_name',}))

 def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name'] # just removed the comma :)
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        return user
```